# Would Carl Jung be considered a postmodernist?

Tags: postmodernism, structuralism, jung

All of Jung's colleagues were modernists, primarily because postmodernism wasn't around yet; they were all Freudian, and, as such, followed the Oedipal grand narrative. Jung, however, had a completely different view of the psyche, similar to the Structuralist model of linguistic meaning: meaning/archetypes are built into the system.

Comment: An alternative name for postmodernism is *post*structuralism, which questions whether even the "structure" can carry "meanings", think of Derrida's deferance. So no, an example of an early postmodernist Freudian would be Lacan.

Comment: I would rather call him a proto-mystic,His views on Alchemy and the 'Chemical Wedding', and his comments about metaphysics line his view up with the perennial view of Reality. I see no signs that he would have had any time for post-modernism.